# Virtual host - SVN - disable direct access from server ip

Tags: debian, virtualhost, svn

I have a debian with apache2 on board. Only port 443 is opened and I'm exposing a SVN with svn_dav.
I want to disable access to my server using ip address only (ie //1.2.3.4) and I want to be able to reach only with https://svn.myserver.com (that is actually working)

Apache is ignoring **fake** virtual host because I can reach my server... I tried with any [suggestion google purphosed](https://www.google.com/search?q=apache%20block%20access%20from%20ip&oq=apache%20block%20access%20from%20ip&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4940j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=93&espv=210&q=apache%20disable%20direct%20access%20from%20server%20ip)... I think that the problem is svn_DAV but modules_enabled/svn_dav.conf doesn't contain anything...

**ports.conf**:

```
[...]
nameVirtualHost *:443
```

**SVN virtual host**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName svn.myserver.com
    ServerAlias svn
    <Location />
        DAV svn
        SVNParentPath /var/svn
        [blablabla]
    </Location>
    [some SSL configuration]
</VirtualHost>
```

**fake virtual host**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/fake
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).  To configure Apache to use it, see this article: [SSL with Virtual Hosts Using SNI](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI).